# Soft power, latching circuit?

Tags: power-supply, power

I'm currently converting an arcade board into a console, and I've been using an original Xbox 360 power supply with it, as it provides 5v and 12v. I thought it would be neat to build a soft-power circuit so that I can hook it up to an arcade button to power it on.

The Xbox 360 power supply provides constant 5vSB.  It provides 12v when 5vSB goes to a control/Enable pin.  So I built the following circuit connected to the 5v line and ground line, with the output split to the arcade board and the control pin:

[image]

This doesn't seem to work.  Pressing the button has no effect with the arcade board plugged in.  With the board disconnected and the power supply running "dry", pressing the button causes the light on the PSU to go green to indicate 12v momentarily, before fading back to the standby yellow.

Should this circuit work as depicted, does it require more components for my specific application, or am I barking up the wrong tree?  I've had a look around for specific examples on this, and I can find a fair bit of information about hooking up devices electrically similar to the 360 to ATX supplies (can't post the links because of low rep) but not so much for going the other way.

EDIT: "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design." – Andy aka, Sparky256, Peter Smith, uint128_t, Daniel Grillo

Except my question WAS regarding electronics design, I even linked to schematics ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What is soft power?

Comment: Measure voltage on the latch output. Does it stay at +5V after pressing the on/off button momentarily? If so then it's working correctly, and the problem is related to its use with the Xbox360 PSU. If not then disconnect the latch output from the PSU and try again. Still no go? Then you may have a wiring error or faulty component.

Comment: ***Except my question WAS regarding electronics design, I even linked to schematics*** FFS this! This question is just about a latching switch! Voting to reopen.

Comment: At the output, add an led and resistor instead of the standby pin. Does it stay on?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed as off-topic.